# how to add tasknum for countbykey() in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark java to write a very easy wordcount program.

buy I wonder how to increase task num for countbykey() function?

I 've tried System.setProperty("spark.default.parallelism", 10) but it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link might be helpful for understanding the need for partitioning: 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections

This codesample might help in your case (working on key-value-pairs):

```
keyValueData = keyValueData.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions));
```

This would partition your JavaPairRDD depending on the hash of your key and the given parameter `numPartitions`.

Now `countByKey` would run with the given number of tasks (`numPartitions`).